# How to remove pop up in iOS app when calling someone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I want to suggest user to make a call from app with one pop up with specific text. I show him first pop-up and if he agrees, then I run a code to make a call from the app. But independently of using `tel://`, `telprompt://`, `tel:` for link, I always get second pop-up from system with phone number in it. How should I change my code to not get this second pop-up from system? 
Searched questions like this here, none one them was helpful.

After these lines of my code second pop-up appears:

```
 NSString *phoneURLString = @"tel://11111111";
 NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL urlWithString:phoneURLString];
 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
 }
```

I have also added to `Info.plist` to section `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` values `tel` and `telprompt`. Will appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen the functionality you are describing in another app ? I dont think you can stop the pop with the number and 'call'

Comment: I haven't seen it in another app myself. I saw comments on stackloverflow implying that such functionality exists.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, what you desire to do is not possible, at least in the existing versions of iOS. That dialog will always show.

Per Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-10.3/) for `openURL`:

> When a third party application invokes openURL: on a tel://,
>   facetime://, or facetime-audio:// URL, iOS displays a prompt and
>   requires user confirmation before dialing.

Comment: thanks for answer, I hope that there is a way around this feature.

Comment: Does anyone know if you can query whether the user has granted permission or not?